# Next.js intercept response

Tags: node.js, next.js

Here is snippet of what my server looks like

```
nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url!, true);
    handleNextRequest(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }).listen(port);
});
```

Once I get the response for the request, how can I append html comment or any tag basically?

What I wanted to do is, before and after body tag, I want to add some comments.

### Current structure

```
<body></body>
```

### What I want

```
<!--someContext-->
  <body> some content </body>
<!--someMoreContext-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by editing the [`_document`](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-document) special file of Next that used as a base template to the page.

```
// ./pages/_document.js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```